# File .env of laravel don't have Mail_lines

Tags: laravel

I have installed laravel 5.0 following a tutorial but when i cheked the .env file of my project this don't have the lines starting with MAIL_ at the end like the tutorial and look like this:
[image]
the project of the tutorial looks like this with lines at the end starting with MAIL_:
[image]
I installed the version of laravel 5.0 like the tutorial but
why in my project the .env file don't have these lines and what problems could cause that?
I installed via composer with this comand: composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 5.0 --prefer-dist i replaced {directory} with a project name

Comment: How did you install Laravel? As even the 5.0 branch of Laravel has those lines: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.0/.env.example

Comment: via composer with this comand: composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 5.0 --prefer-dist i replaced {directory} with a project name

Comment: give us link to tutorial u red

Comment: from a youtube tutorial (is in spanish) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGQGWVwbK5I

Comment: use this tutorial http://laravel.com/docs/ in right-top corner u can choose version of tutorial

Comment: The mail config values were added _after_ 5.0: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8e15c7f73ebb541967560a38b46ea75d58dfaa02/.env.example

Answer (score 1):

It depends on wich exactly version of Laravel u have.

MAIL_ in .env appeared on Feb 23, 2015

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/8e15c7f73ebb541967560a38b46ea75d58dfaa02

i think it is v5.0.16

In v5.0.0 we have this: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/78b9b7d9b9e43aeb79bf80f1251927d29ab7fe7e/.env.example

All is ok

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.0.16/.env.example
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.0.0/.env.example